# How To Edit a Lotus Notes Database Entry with Lotus Notes

Tags: powershell, lotus

```
$outfile = "c:\tools\010422.txt"
#... Set some variables
$strDominoDir = 'acct/FileName.nsf'
$strHubServer = 'ServerName'
$strUserView = 'UseView' 

#... Setup the notes Session connection
$notes = new-object -comobject Lotus.NotesSession
$notes.initialize() 

#... Get a handle on the Domino Directory
$dbNAB = $notes.GetDatabase( $strHubServer, $strDominoDir, 1 ) 
write-Host $dbNAB.Title " : Database Now Open for business" 

#... Get a handle on a View from the Domino Directory
$vwUsers = $dbNAB.GetView( $strUserView ) 
Write-Host $vwUsers.Name " : View Now Open for business" 

$counterF = $vwUsers.GetFirstDocument()
while($CounterF -ne $null){
    $DomNexDocument = $vwUsers.GetNextDocument($CounterF) #Define Next doc                
    Write-Host "$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[3]);$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[2]);$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[10]);$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[6])"                
    $CounterF = $DomNexDocument #Raise counter
    add-content $outfile "$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[3]);$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[2]);$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[10]);$($DomNexDocument.ColumnValues[6])"                
}
```

Good Morning,
I have put this code together from various websites in order to be able to connect to a lotus notes database and get the column titles from the database.  I seem to be falling flat on my face though when trying to figure out how to use this information to get the actual database entry and modify it.  Any help is appreciated.
Daniel

Comment: Notes Client installed? Where do you fail? Are the variables pointing to the right Domino server, fileName and viewname? You know, that in every Domino Domain there is most probably more than one server, every server hosts multiple databases and every database contains multiple views... So which is it that you want to get?

Comment: Yes, i have the correct server names.  I can view the database without issue and retrieve the column names of said database.  I just cant figure out how to point towards the actual database entry so i can edit it.

Comment: Edit how? In Notes? Or do you want to modify an entry using PowerShell? And which "actual entry"?